# C# navigation service goback

Tags: c#, navigationservice

I wan't to know the name to the back Window.

I don't how can I make that.

For the moment, my code is :

```
if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its my example -> Scenes - its my Frame in mainpage
you can rewrite Scenes to this

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EventRegistration();
}

private void EventRegistration()
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    Scenes.Navigated += OnNavigated;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        Scenes.CanGoBack ?
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}

private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Frame)
    {
        var sc = sender as Frame;
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        sc.CanGoBack ?
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Scenes.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Scenes.GoBack();
    }
}
```